# SQL - Subquery (Column names)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a select query thats returns the value of some columns.
The column that I want starts with 'U_S'.

```
Select * from em
```

I need to transform the query above. The '*' needs to be the result (but with commas) of:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='em' and column_name like 'u_s%'
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all the Column names that start with `U_S` from all the tables in a database ?

Comment: You will have to dynamically generate the SQL and then execute that with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) in a stored procedure. You can use @johncappelletti's excellent answer below to get your list of fields comma separated.

Comment: Why don't you know what columns your table contains? That smells like a very bad database design.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I know what columns my table contains, but I need the code to be responsive when you add or remove columns.

Comment: But why would you add a column or remove columns and want to react on it depending on its name? That sounds strange. Table structures are supposed to be static and when you really add a column some day then it has a meaning for certain processes that must be adjusted, while other processes are oblivious to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are countless examples like this, but I understand that sometimes we all need a little kick-start.

```
Select Stuff((Select ',' +quotename(Column_Name) 
  From information_schema.columns 
  Where table_name='em' and column_name like 'u_s%'
  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: It returns the data like was expected. But I can't use it in another query. Like: select @mytemp from em

Comment: @HugoNunes You would have to go DYNAMIC if that was your intent

Answer (score 1):

you can use code like below:

```
declare @col varchar(500)
select @col=Stuff((Select ',' +quotename(Column_Name) 
  From information_schema.columns 
  Where table_name='em' and column_name like 'u_s%'
  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
exec('select '+@col
  +' from em')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST(
    (select COLUMN_NAME + ',' 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name='em' and column_name like 'u_s%'
    for xml path('')
    ) as nvarchar(max)
)
```

you will have to delete last comma...

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the column names directly into a variable, which can then be used for a Dynamic SQL.

```
declare @Cols varchar(max) = null;

select @Cols = concat(@Cols +', ',quotename(COLUMN_NAME))
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='em' and column_name like 'u_s%'
order by column_name;

--select @Cols as Cols;
declare @SQL varchar(max);
set @SQL = 'select '+ @Cols +' from em';
exec(@SQL);
```

@Cols is null at first, and null+',' gives null.
So the result won't start with a comma.

The quotename function is just added as a safety measure.
Just in case the columnnames sometimes have spaces in the name.